# Excel CSV String Not Fully Uploading To Excel

Tags: mysql, excel, csv

I have this string in Excel (I've UTF encoded It) when I save as CSV and import to MySql I get only the below, I know it's probably a charset issue but could you explain why as I'm having difficulty understanding it.

In Excel Cell:

```
PARTY HARD PAYDAY SPECIAL â UPTO Â£40 OFF EVENT PACKAGES INCLUDING HOTTEST EVENTS! MUST END SUNDAY! http://bit.ly/1Gzrw9H
```

Ends up in DB:

```
PARTY HARD PAYDAY SPECIAL
```

The field is structured to be `utf8_general_ci` encoded and `VARCHAR(10000)`

Answer (score 0):

Mysql does not support full unicode utf8. There are some 4 byte characters that cannot be processed and, I guess, stored properly in regular utf8. I am assuming that upon import it is truncating the value after SPECIAL since mysql does not know how to process or store the character in the string that comes after that.

In order to handle full utf8 with 4 byte characters you will have to switch over to the utf8mb4.

This is from the mysql documentation:

> The character set named utf8 uses a maximum of three bytes per character and contains only BMP characters. The utf8mb4 character set uses a maximum of four bytes per character supports supplemental characters...

You can read more here [@dev.mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-unicode-utf8mb4.html)

Also, [Here](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) is a great detailed explanation on reg-utf8 issues in mysql and how to switch to utf8mb4.